# Passing list index as an argument in subprocess.call()

Tags: python, list

I'm not sure what's wrong here. I'm getting 0 0 0 0 as a output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

fourletterwords = ["srvr", "stat", "mntr"]

for fourlw in fourletterwords:

    output = subprocess.call("echo {fourlw} | nc localhost 2181", shell=True)

    print (output)
```

Comment: Because the output of subprocess.call is the exit status, not whatever is written to standard out

Comment: You missed an `f` in the `call` function too. It should be `subprocess.call(f"echo {fourlw} | nc localhost 2181", shell=True)`

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `subprocess.call()` is the the return code, i.e. the exit status, of the call, not the output.  Try using `subprocess.check_output()` instead:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(f"echo {fourlw} | nc localhost 2181", shell=True)
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)